# WFFM Error Alert: This action cannot be added. Your configuration does not support it

Tags: wffm

I added a custom action to Save actions of a WFFM (9.0.1) form in Sitecore 9.0.1. 
While linking Form submit button to created custom action, got an alert,  saying "This action cannot be added. Your configuration does not support it."

Installed WFFM and with compatible sitecore version.

What could be the possible reason for this?
[image: WFFM custom submit action dll]
[image: WFFM custom submit action item]
[image: linking custom submit action item to WFFM form]

Comment: Please check whether you are referencing correct assembly in your custom Save action + check whether it inherits WffmSaveAction class

Comment: I have attached two images and It inherits correct class as you can see in attached image

Comment: Take a look here -> https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/7/t/2371. One of the comments says that you need to inherit WffmSaveAction  not ISaveAction ...

Comment: The question is already on our site. While I realise the existing answer only has a "solution" for 9.1, we're going to need a 9.0.x answer added on the original - not on this one.

Comment: Your issue was that the system couldn't find your mentioned class for the save action, because you did create a class, but didn't deploy yet. you have to deploy, refresh and try the same action again it will work.